# Android Studio Geolocation function

Tags: java, android, android-studio, geolocation, location

I'm creating an application in android studio which uses bluetooth to create an ad hoc network between devices so they can send emergency messages to each other. When a device recieves an emergency message an alarm sounds on the app. Once the user hears the alarm, just like a fire alarm they are supposed to exit the building and once they have exit the building they press a button to say they have exit the building and the alarm sound stops.

Now is it possible using geolocation services to have the alarm sound until the user gets to a certain location such as a place outside of the building?

Thanks!

Comment: Look into geofencing - it works both ways, entry and exit.  So when the emergency message is received, establish a geofence on current location and process the exit condition.  https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html

Answer (score 0):

Use android emulator, and use `geo fix` command to change your location.

Details: Mocking location data
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html#MockData

Otherwise, you can use your own foot or car to change your location.